# Xcode app with two buttons. Actions for both are fired when I click either one. Why does that happen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter

It's a sample Twitter application that I made folllowing the tutorial in Apple's developer site. But I don't know what I did wrong for this to happen.

Interface:

```
@interface TWTViewController : UIViewController {
NSString* output;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* output;
- (IBAction)doTweet:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)getTimeline:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *tweetButton;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation TWTViewController
@synthesize output = _output;
@synthesize outputLabel;
@synthesize tweetButton;

...

- (IBAction)doTweet:(id)sender {
    TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [twitter setInitialText:@"It's really that simple!"];
    [twitter addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"]];
    [self presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:nil];
    twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult res) {
        if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Your Tweet was posted succesfully." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertView show];
        }
        else if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your Tweet was not posted." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };
}

- (IBAction)getTimeline:(id)sender {
    ACAccountStore* store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType* twitterAccountType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            NSArray* twitterAccounts = [store accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];
            if([twitterAccounts count] > 0) {
                ACAccount* account = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [params setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];
                NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];
                TWRequest* request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:params requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
                [request setAccount:account];
                [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    if(error != nil) {
                        self.output = [error localizedDescription];
                        self.outputLabel.text = self.output;
                    }
                    else {
                        NSError* jsonError;
                        NSArray* timeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&jsonError];
                        if(jsonError == nil) {
                            self.output = [timeline componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
                            self.outputLabel.text = self.output;
                        }
                        else {
                            self.output = [jsonError localizedDescription];
                            self.outputLabel.text = self.output;
                        }
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
@end
```

Here's the ZIP file containing the whole project: http://www.mediafire.com/?yi4x3d6qn1x4p4r

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what kind of help? what have you done? what is the problem? why would anybody just download the whole project?

Comment: @Sarah **Problem:** I click button1. Action for button1 is triggered. Action for button2 is also triggered. I need help figuring out why. I can't find anything wrong with the code, that's why I shared the project, thinking someone more experienced could find out what's wrong. It's a very tiny project, only a few hundred KBs.

Comment: Downloaded. your project is lacking the accounts and twitter framework.Gives error for the same. Need to be run is IOS device only.No provision profile. Not able to test it. Can u do something on that part?

Comment: @Sarah Accounts.Framework and Twitter.Framework are parts of the iOS5 SDK. They can be found in the folder **/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks**. What's a "provision profile"? (I have added the code in the original post now.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check ALL of your connections in IB.  I know it sounds stupid but it gets me all the time...

Comment: Yes, that helped! This was in the storyboard file:

    <connections>
    <action selector="doTweet:" destination="2" eventType="touchUpInside" id="FGm-ZF-Nub"/>
    <action selector="getTimeline:" destination="2" eventType="touchUpInside" id="v2w-rF-SUX"/>
    </connections>

Answer (score 2):

The "Get Timeline" button is currently set to fire both `doTweet:` and `getTimeline:`.  Right-click the Get Timeline button in IB and you'll see both listed under Sent Events->Touch Up Inside.  Click the little X next to `doTweet:`, and you should be all good.

@Szwedo's advice is good; always check your connections and actions in IB.